# Get blockchain info for exchange transaction

Tags: transactions, blockchain, exchanges, blockchain.info

I'm sorry in advanced if this questions are dumb but here goes ...

Does all buy/sell bitcoin related transactions made in exchanges get logged in the blockchain? if so can they be found and/or tracked somehow using API?

**Example**

Given the following data recieved from BTER API describing some transaction in the BTC-CNY market

```
{
    date: "1442039516",
    price: 1544,
    amount: 0.01,
    tid: "11958597",
    type: "buy"
}
```

Is it possible to find the from/to addresses of this transaction? if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orders on exchanges are completely internal, there is no corresponding transaction made in the Bitcoin network. The volume of transactions happening on Bitcoin exchanges far exceeds the total number of Bitcoin network transactions, it's not feasible on many levels for it to work this way, even just from a latency and confirmation perspective.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not talking about orders in the exchanges orderbooks I mean the tradebook like trades that were actually confirmed

Comment: Is that the same?

Comment: Yes, no exchange has ever worked like that.